# MySQL DBUG_PRINT

Tags: mysql

I want to print from MYSQL.

So DBUG_PRINT function was used and mysql was executed in debug mode.

```
mysql -u~~~ -p --debug=d:t:i:O,/tmp/mysqld.trace
```

However DBUG_PRINT is not visible in mysqld.trace.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: can you explain what you trying to do or what you try to debug. if you enable debugging mode, only if you encounter a error which can be traced. so usually you don't encounter these (hopeully)

Comment: I want to simply check what I'm doing on the server, such as printing a string for a specific variable.

Comment: ex) sql_parse.cc
printf(string); It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In default MySQL builds, these options are disabled. This is noted in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/debugging-client.html):

> To be able to debug a MySQL client with the integrated debug package, you should configure MySQL with `-DWITH_DEBUG=1`. See Section 2.9.7, “MySQL Source-Configuration Options”.

That is, you would need to build the MySQL client from source yourself, not use a standard binary distribution.